# Adding weight to a font in xetex

Tags: xetex, fontspec

My monospaced font in Xetex is Courier New, but appears too thin on screen.  I can switch to the bold version, but that's too heavy.  Is there is a way with Xetex and fontspec to add some weight to a font?

```
\setmonofont{Courier New}       % too thin
\setmonofont{Courier New Bold}  % too heavy
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it's not typographically the best idea ever: see `FakeBold` in the manual. Alternatively, check out different monospace fonts such as 'Inconsolata’ — much better, IMO, than Courier.

Comment: I think any monospaced font is better than Courier.